# file upload from phone directory

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to upload a particular file on server, which is stored in iphone directory.

Simply, to upload any file we can use the "Browse" button.

When you click on this button we can get the file directory and choose any file & we can upload the particular file.

I do the same thing here.

suppose, I am stored the doc file in iphone and i want to upload this file on server which path are not available. but i get the path on using the browse file.In short browse content is my problem.

Comment: have you tried anything? have you got any problem with your code? please first try yourself , do Google about your problem and if have any problem than post here

Comment: i can't not access my phone directory.. i can only access the sandbox...so is it possible to access the phone directory?

Comment: Saurabh have you any knowledge about this?

Comment: No, but if you have some code than please post it here. i am also searching for it. i do my best to help you

Comment: Yes, i am also searching, ThaNk you for your reply